# Composite primary key better than unique index exclusion in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, unique, integrity

I am in the process of designing a database. I am taking my time to try to understand the key difference between using a unique index (using **GIST EXCLUDE** to enforce a specific business rule) and achieving the same result using a composite primary key.

In what case would it be proper to use a composite primary key to achieve uniqueness vs. using a unique index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one notable difference between a primary key constraint and mere uniqueness: primary key columns have to be `NOT NULL`. The main purpose of a primary key is to ascertain that there cannot be two identical rows in a table. If the columns in your exclusion constraint are `NOT NULL`, and it truly excludes identical rows, it will serve that purpose just as well.

There is one other difference between a primary key constraint and a unique exclusion constraint: the former can be referenced by a foreign key constraint, while the latter cannot. So I would say that you can safely go with only your exclusion constraint (provided it guarantees uniqueness), unless you need the columns to be the target of a foreign key constraint.

Comment: thanks for explanation , the exclusion constraint can never be null as fields are defined this way on column level. I love that i can use an expression on the unique exclusion index. creating a composite key means that I have to have a field in a ready format since I can't use expression on fields marked as primary keys. I will give it a little more thought but thanks for the answer again !